# Adding elements in to array in C, while maintaining ascending order

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I need an addArray function in C, which adds given element to a given array, making sure that every element is inserted in a correct spot in the array, so that the order of integers are in ascending order.

- Prototype int addArray (int *arr, int sizeofArray, int numToAdd)
- Find the correct index to insert.
- Move other elements to adjust.
- Store the new element at correct index
- Return the size of array.

Can I get any help for this function.

```
int addToArray(int *array, int size, int selectedNum){
    //printf("Selected number is %d \n", selectedNum);
    int indexToInsert=0;
    if(size==0){
        array[indexToInsert]=selectedNum;
        size=1;
        indexToInsert++;
        return size;
    }
    else{

        for(int i=size; i<=1; i--){
            if(selectedNum>array[i]){
                indexToInsert=i-1;
                break;
            }
            else{
                }
        }
        if(indexToInsert>0){
            for(int j=size-1; j>indexToInsert; j--){
                array[j+1]=array[j];
            }
            array[indexToInsert]=selectedNum;
            size = size+1;
            printf("Size incremented to %d\n", size);
            return size;
}
```

Requirement is: do not simply add element to array and sort. It has to be stored in the correct index. This is what I have for this function. It is not working properly. The main program is prompting the user, until it enters a negative num, and each positive number is being added to the array in an ascending order.

Comment: I hate to be "that guy". But this is not a homework site. Show us what you have tried and what went wrong.

Comment: how can i put my work here. i tried to copy paste it says too long. can you suggest me. thanks

Comment: While Inserting The Element Compare With Elements.And Then Place It Accordingly.

Comment: I am trying to compare, but something is wrong in my logic. I am trying to upload the code, how can i do that?

Comment: i tried to cut and paste its giving me this. sorry. any other idea.?

Comment: Inserting into an array is the mirror image of deleting from an array, and you have to do the same type of operations.  Therefore, I believe the duplicate is appropriate — you need to shift right instead of shift left, that's all.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, The right shift is (slightly) more complicated because an element has to be written to the index that is the beginning of the shift and potentially the shift could go out of bounds by one index

Answer (score 2):

The choice of array is not very wise when there is a lot of insertion operations in between or at any random positions, as moving the rest of the array(post insertion) elements by +1 position would be a very *costly* affair.

Better way: Use multimap or priority-queue which store the values in ascending order by default, permitting duplicate values as key.. Then iterate from the start till the end of the map to store keys in array.

```
TC: O(NlogN) for insertions + O(N) for last traversal of map => O(NlogN).
```

If you still want to use array and no other data structure, then employ [binary search mechanism](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36221/binary-search-for-inserting-in-array) while doing insertion operations.

```
TC: O(NlogN) for insertions + O(N^2) for moving => O(N^2).
Worst case scenario: when the input stream is in descending order, and 
                     the final array is expected to be in ascending order.
```

Comment: we are to use the array specifically. no linked list are allowed.

Comment: Use binary search mechanism to do insertions. That is the best bet I am afraid.

Comment: I want to enter each element to the array, and compare that num to the numbers present(if any), then put the num to be inserted in the correct index. And move the remaining elements one index right.